# making an ajax query with an array in parameters

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to make an Ajax query with an array in the parameters. Here's an example :

```
var info = [ter,ter,ter];

$('body').on('click','#upload', function(){
    $.ajax({
        url:'/app_dev.php/uploader_photos',
        data:{
            links : info,
        },
        dataType : 'json',
        beforeSend : function(){
            $('#upload_photo').empty();
            $('#upload_photo').append('<i class="fa fa-refresh fa-spin"></i> Loading');
        },
        success : function(data){
            $('#upload_photo').empty();
            $('#upload_photo').append('<i class="fa fa-thumbs-o-up"></i> OK');
        }
    });
});
```

The issue is my url is encoded this way :

```
/upload?links%5B%5D=ter&lioks%5B%5D=ter&lioks%5B%5D=ter
```

What i need to know how to encode it this way :

```
/upload?links=[ter,ter,ter]
```

Thanks for the help !

Comment: be sure to accept one of the answers as well as optionally voting. thank you.

Answer (score 2):

That shouldn't be a problem actually. As you have not set the `Content-Type` so by default jQuery uses `formurlencoded` query string so it encodes the values that way and it sends it as a `form data` instead of `Request Payload`.

You can get it like:

```
if(isset($_GET['links'])){
  echo $_GET['links'];
}
```

From the docs:

> **contentType (default: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8')**
>   ***Type: Boolean or String***
>   When sending data to the server, use this content type. Default is "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8", which is fine for most cases. If you explicitly pass in a content-type to $.ajax(), then it is always sent to the server (even if no data is sent). As of jQuery 1.6 you can pass false to tell jQuery to not set any content type header. Note: The W3C XMLHttpRequest specification dictates that the charset is always UTF-8; specifying another charset will not force the browser to change the encoding. Note: For cross-domain requests, setting the content type to anything other than application/x-www-form-urlencoded, multipart/form-data, or text/plain will trigger the browser to send a preflight OPTIONS request to the server.

Answer (score 2):

Stringify your array to json:

`info = JSON.stringify(info);`

in your php:

`$info = json_decode($_POST['links']);`

Answer (score 1):

This will convert a native JavaScript object to a JSON string:

```
JSON.stringify(yourString);
```

so, in your code:

```
links : JSON.stringify(info),
```